# Outlook add-in appears on OWA, doesn't appear on Outlook 2013 client, on-premise Exchange 2013 server

Tags: outlook, office-js

This is in an Enterprise setup (had a lot of GPO set) running Exchange 2013 Server, with Outlook 2013 client.

I installed the add-in using OWA

`Manage Add-ins > Add from file`

The add-in appeared in and worked fine

When I open outlook 2013, I do not see the add-in appear, tried a lot of steps to debug.

As per this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/troubleshoot-outlook-add-in-activation

1. Version no was `?Session.ExchangeMailboxServerVersion`

   `15.0.1320.4000`
2. Is the add-in disabled?

   `Enabled`
3. Is the add-in manifest installed properly, and does Outlook have a cached copy?
   `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Office\15.0\WEF` `\<insert your guid>\<insert base 64 hash>\Manifests\<ManifestID>_<ManifestVersion>`

The new added add-in files would get removed everytime the data is pulled from exchange servers. Only 3 default add-in files were available.

4. Checked Windows Logs in Eventviewer
   `The Exchange web service request GetAppManifests succeeded.`

   Got this message with event id `63`

We also checked `Fiddler` and could see the call going to get the manifests but that would give the manifest of only 3 add-ins that come installed by default on Exchange Setup.

For the same account, the add-in works fine in a `Virtual Environment, VDI setup`. But doesn't appear on the desktop environment, if that helps.

To rule out the possibility of a wrong manifest file, we tried using the `Outlook Command Demo Add-in`. This also worked on `Virtual Environment, VDI setup`. But doesn't appear on the desktop environment.

Are there any other steps that can help us debug this? Any directory where logs are available for add-ins?

We have hit a roadblock due to this with no idea how to debug/get it working.

Comment: The version you have there is the exchange version number, not the Outlook Client Version. Outlook Client Version can be obtained by going to File->Office Account->About Outlook. If you are not on 15.0.4805.XXXX or greater, that version of Outlook does not support the Add-in Commands API Set. (1.3). If your manifest is at a greater API set, then it will not be downloaded since that version of outlook does not support it. Note that to support Add-in Commands (buttons in the ribbon) you will need to upgrade 3 binaries. Osf, Outlook and MSO: See these links:

Comment: Outlook Patch
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114829
Mso Patch:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114816
Osf patch:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114828 

But you should try and upgrade everything to the latest versions for more API support and bug fixes.

Comment: On desktop the outlook version is v15.0.4420.. our manifest doesn't have ribbon stuff and mailbox version required.is 1.1.. so shouldn't it be supported in this version of Outlook?

Comment: 15.0.4420 is the RTM version of Outlook 2013. Mailbox requirement set 1.1 was introduced in Outlook 2013 SP1, so the add-in will only appear in Outlook 2013 SP1 and later.